# Meaning of dot (.) in The Following Examples

Tags: shell, directory

I would like to know the meaning of the dot (.) in the following examples:

dotslash at the front of the path:

```
cp -r ./dist/amd/ ../../aurelia-amd/animator-css
```

Is this equivalent to

```
cp -r dist/amd/ ../../aurelia-amd/animator-css
```

dot at the end of the destination path:

```
cp -r DEBIAN/amd64/* package/riaps-pycom-amd64/DEBIAN/.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single dots, in these examples, can be removed.

`dist` and `./dist` are the same things, as is `package/riaps-pycom-amd64/DEBIAN/.` and `package/riaps-pycom-amd64/DEBIAN/`.

The dot, when used as part of a pathname, means "this directory".  In `DEBIAN/.` it is like saying "in the `DEBIAN` directory, *here*".

Technically, the dot is a hard link to (i.e. another name for) the same directory that it is located in, and is available in every single directory on a Unix system.  Likewise, the double-dot is another name for the parent directory.

---

Side note:

`DEBIAN/` and `DEBIAN` are only slightly different if `DEBIAN` is a symbolic link.  If it is not a symbolic link, then they are the same, but if `DEBIAN` is a symbolic link, then `DEBIAN` would refer to the symbolic link itself (which the utility, `cp` in this case, would resolve to a directory), while `DEBIAN/` would be resolved to a directory by the shell.

The trailing `/` may also be interpreted by the utility in special ways under some circumstances.  A typical example is the source location of `rsync`.  With a trailing `/` on the source, `rsync -r` or `rsync -a` would copy the *contents* of the directory, but would create a subdirectory for the contents if the source was specified without a trailing `/`.

Comment: Also, when in an interactive bash session, the `./` is useful to narrow tab-completion results to the current directory (for example, if $CDPATH is set, tab-completion may pick up subdirectories from $CDPATH directories), or for oddly named files (for example if a file is named `-l` then `ls -l` and `ls ./-l` will give different results).